# Running multiple stored procs on big query

Tags: stored-procedures, google-bigquery

I have 100+ stored procs I need to execute in big query. Is there a way to execute them in parallel? My idea was to just run them one after the other in multiple editors. Call SP1(); call SP2(); call SP3(); etc any faster or more efficient way? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you run your queries/Stored Procedure script in BigQuery, under the hood it tries to parallelize the process by distributing work between it's resources(worker nodes). There isn't much manual optimization that you can do here. However, you can try using BigQuery [client](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries) libraries to implement multi-threading to optimize and run the processes in parallel.